# how to map cities points to US map with shifted coordinates to allow for space between regions?

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, spatial, coordinate-systems

I would like to plot a map of the US using `ggplot2` where the map is divided into 1 of 4 regions with blank spaces b/w each. Additionally, I have a set of city coordinates I would like to map onto each region. My issue is the following. I can create the map just fine, but I cannot get the city coordinate points to fall on the map. I understand that adding spaces between the region necessitates changing the coordinates for the map but I've also changed the coordinates for the cities accordingly such that I thought they would shift with on another but the whole thing is a mess...

```
library(maps)
library(ggplot2)

us.map <-  map_data('state')

# add map regions
us.map$PADD[us.map$region %in% 
          c("connecticut", "maine", "massachusetts", "new hampshire", "rhode island", "vermont", "new jersey", "new york", "pennsylvania")] <- "PADD 1: East Coast"
us.map$PADD[us.map$region %in% 
          c("illinois", "indiana", "michigan", "ohio", "wisconsin", "iowa", "kansas", "minnesota", "missouri", "nebraska", "north dakota", "south dakota")] <- "PADD 2: Midwest"
us.map$PADD[us.map$region %in% 
          c("delaware", "florida", "georgia", "maryland", "north carolina", "south carolina", "virginia", "district of columbia", "west virginia", "alabama", "kentucky", "mississippi", "tennessee", "arkansas", "louisiana", "oklahoma", "texas")] <- "PADD 3: Gulf Coast"
us.map$PADD[us.map$region %in% 
          c("alaska", "california", "hawaii", "oregon", "washington", "arizona", "colorado", "idaho", "montana", "nevada", "new mexico", "utah", "wyoming")] <- "PADD 4: West Coast"

# subset the dataframe by region (PADD) and move lat/lon accordingly
us.map$lat.transp[us.map$PADD == "PADD 1: East Coast"] <- us.map$lat[us.map$PADD == "PADD 1: East Coast"]
us.map$long.transp[us.map$PADD == "PADD 1: East Coast"] <- us.map$long[us.map$PADD == "PADD 1: East Coast"] + 5

us.map$lat.transp[us.map$PADD == "PADD 2: Midwest"] <- us.map$lat[us.map$PADD == "PADD 2: Midwest"]
us.map$long.transp[us.map$PADD == "PADD 2: Midwest"] <- us.map$long[us.map$PADD == "PADD 2: Midwest"]

us.map$lat.transp[us.map$PADD == "PADD 3: Gulf Coast"] <- us.map$lat[us.map$PADD == "PADD 3: Gulf Coast"] - 3
us.map$long.transp[us.map$PADD == "PADD 3: Gulf Coast"] <- us.map$long[us.map$PADD == "PADD 3: Gulf Coast"]

us.map$lat.transp[us.map$PADD == "PADD 4: West Coast"] <- us.map$lat[us.map$PADD == "PADD 4: West Coast"] - 2
us.map$long.transp[us.map$PADD == "PADD 4: West Coast"] <- us.map$long[us.map$PADD == "PADD 4: West Coast"] - 10

# plot 
ggplot(us.map,  aes(x=long.transp, y=lat.transp), colour="white") + 
  geom_polygon(aes(group = group, fill="red")) +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(),  # remove background
    panel.grid = element_blank(), 
    axis.line = element_blank(), 
    axis.title = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    axis.text = element_blank()) +
  coord_equal()+ scale_fill_manual(values="lightgrey", guide=FALSE)
```

That results in the following:

[image]

which is fine (some code obtained from: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141181/how-to-create-a-us-map-in-r-with-separation-between-states-and-clear-labels) but I would like to map a set of coordinates to it.

Link for two compressed datasets, `cities2.csv` and `PADDS.csv` used below: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/zh9xyiakeuhgmdy/Archive.zip?dl=0 (sorry, data is too large to enter using `dput`)

```
#Two datasets found on dropbox link in zip 
cities<-read.csv("cities2.csv")
padds<-read.csv("PADDS.csv")
padds$State<-NULL

colnames(padds)<-c("state","PADD")
points<-merge(cities, padds, by="state",all.x=TRUE)

#Shift city coordinates according to padd region
points$Long2<-ifelse(points$PADD =="PADD 1: East Coast", points$Long+5,  points$Long)
points$Long2<-ifelse(points$PADD =="PADD 4: West Coast", points$Long-10,  points$Long2)

points$Lat2<-ifelse(points$PADD =="PADD 3: Gulf Coast", points$Lat-3,  points$Lat)
points$Lat2<-ifelse(points$PADD =="PADD 4: West Coast", points$Lat-2,  points$Lat2)
```

That results in the following:

[image]

Clearly something is going wrong here... Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the coordinates in your `cities` CSV file are wrong. Below is how I check the coordinates. I first downloaded your CSV file, read in the file as `cities`, and then I created an `sf` object and visualized it with the [mapview](/questions/tagged/mapview) package.

```
colnames(cities) <- c("state", "Lat", "Long")

library(sf)
library(mapview)

cities_sf <- cities %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("Long", "Lat"), crs = 4326)

mapview(cities_sf)
```

[image]

As you can see, the latitudes seem to be right, but the longitudes are all wrong. However, it seems like you just have the wrong sign of the longitudes because I can still see the shape of US based on these dots.

So, here is a quick fix.

```
library(dplyr)
cities2 <- cities %>% mutate(Long = -Long)

cities_sf2 <- cities2 %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("Long", "Lat"), crs = 4326)

mapview(cities_sf2)
```

[image]

Now the coordinates in `cities2` are correct. So we can run your code to map the cities.

```
colnames(padds)<-c("state","PADD")
points<-merge(cities2, padds, by="state",all.x=TRUE)

points$Long2<-ifelse(points$PADD  %in% "PADD 1: East Coast", points$Long+5,  points$Long)
points$Long2<-ifelse(points$PADD %in% "PADD 4: West Coast", points$Long-10,  points$Long2)

points$Lat2<-ifelse(points$PADD %in% "PADD 3: Gulf Coast", points$Lat-3,  points$Lat)
points$Lat2<-ifelse(points$PADD %in% "PADD 4: West Coast", points$Lat-2,  points$Lat2)

# P is the ggplot object you created earlier    
P + geom_point(data = points, aes(x = Long2, y = Lat2))
```

[image]

**Update**

Here is the full code requested by the OP.

```
library(maps)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

#Two datasets found on dropbox link in zip 
cities<-read.csv("cities.csv")
padds<-read.csv("PADDS.csv")
padds$State<-NULL

colnames(cities) <- c("state", "Lat", "Long")
colnames(padds)<-c("state","PADD")

cities2 <- cities %>% mutate(Long = -Long)

points<-merge(cities2, padds, by="state",all.x=TRUE)

#Shift city coordinates according to padd region
points$Long2<-ifelse(points$PADD =="PADD 1: East Coast", points$Long+5,  points$Long)
points$Long2<-ifelse(points$PADD =="PADD 4: West Coast", points$Long-10,  points$Long2)

points$Lat2<-ifelse(points$PADD =="PADD 3: Gulf Coast", points$Lat-3,  points$Lat)
points$Lat2<-ifelse(points$PADD =="PADD 4: West Coast", points$Lat-2,  points$Lat2)

us.map <-  map_data('state')

# add map regions
us.map$PADD[us.map$region %in% 
              c("connecticut", "maine", "massachusetts", "new hampshire", "rhode island", "vermont", "new jersey", "new york", "pennsylvania")] <- "PADD 1: East Coast"
us.map$PADD[us.map$region %in% 
              c("illinois", "indiana", "michigan", "ohio", "wisconsin", "iowa", "kansas", "minnesota", "missouri", "nebraska", "north dakota", "south dakota")] <- "PADD 2: Midwest"
us.map$PADD[us.map$region %in% 
              c("delaware", "florida", "georgia", "maryland", "north carolina", "south carolina", "virginia", "district of columbia", "west virginia", "alabama", "kentucky", "mississippi", "tennessee", "arkansas", "louisiana", "oklahoma", "texas")] <- "PADD 3: Gulf Coast"
us.map$PADD[us.map$region %in% 
              c("alaska", "california", "hawaii", "oregon", "washington", "arizona", "colorado", "idaho", "montana", "nevada", "new mexico", "utah", "wyoming")] <- "PADD 4: West Coast"

# subset the dataframe by region (PADD) and move lat/lon accordingly
us.map$lat.transp[us.map$PADD == "PADD 1: East Coast"] <- us.map$lat[us.map$PADD == "PADD 1: East Coast"]
us.map$long.transp[us.map$PADD == "PADD 1: East Coast"] <- us.map$long[us.map$PADD == "PADD 1: East Coast"] + 5

us.map$lat.transp[us.map$PADD == "PADD 2: Midwest"] <- us.map$lat[us.map$PADD == "PADD 2: Midwest"]
us.map$long.transp[us.map$PADD == "PADD 2: Midwest"] <- us.map$long[us.map$PADD == "PADD 2: Midwest"]

us.map$lat.transp[us.map$PADD == "PADD 3: Gulf Coast"] <- us.map$lat[us.map$PADD == "PADD 3: Gulf Coast"] - 3
us.map$long.transp[us.map$PADD == "PADD 3: Gulf Coast"] <- us.map$long[us.map$PADD == "PADD 3: Gulf Coast"]

us.map$lat.transp[us.map$PADD == "PADD 4: West Coast"] <- us.map$lat[us.map$PADD == "PADD 4: West Coast"] - 2
us.map$long.transp[us.map$PADD == "PADD 4: West Coast"] <- us.map$long[us.map$PADD == "PADD 4: West Coast"] - 10

# plot 
P <- ggplot(us.map,  aes(x=long.transp, y=lat.transp), colour="white") + 
  geom_polygon(aes(group = group, fill="red")) +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(),  # remove background
        panel.grid = element_blank(), 
        axis.line = element_blank(), 
        axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_blank()) +
  coord_equal()+ scale_fill_manual(values="lightgrey", guide=FALSE)

# P is the ggplot object you created earlier    
P + geom_point(data = points, aes(x = Long2, y = Lat2))
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, this is what i want except that I'm having trouble reproducing that map,  could you provide me with your full code from start to finish? thank you!

Comment: I have posted my full code already. After read in the `cities` CSV file, I noticed that the column names are different than your code. So I added `colnames(cities) <- c("state", "Lat", "Long")`. The other thing I did is saving your previous `ggplot2` code to `p` so that I can add points on it. Thant is all.

Comment: The key is your longitudes are wrong. After correcting the longitude, I believe your code should work.

Comment: I dont know what to tell you, I get something different than what you have. I appreciate the effort, can you perhaps provide step by step code. Don't post extra code thats unnecessary -just the code used to solve the question asked. Thanks.

Comment: @CyrusMohammadian Please see my update as the full code. Most of them are from you. So I think once you fixed the longitudes it should be fine.

Answer (score 3):

Interesting question! Here is a solution based on the `sf` package, which can potentially also make it easier to combine a plot like this with other spatial data. The approach goes:

1. Get state boundaries from a different package `USAboundaries::us_states()` rather than `ggplot2::map_data`, because converting the individual points into polygons would be a waste of time
2. Convert the cities coordinates into points with `st_as_sf`, set their coordinate system, and fix the incorrect sign of the coordinates as the other answer noted. (N.B. manually removed nonstandard character from colname)
3. Combine the files, add the region labelling, and remove Alaska, Hawaii and Puerto Rico (since they would make the plot look weird and you didn't use them)
4. Use `st_set_geometry` to replace the shapes with the desired translated shapes (just do `+ c(x, y)`). Note that `sf` uses `(x, y)` for its affine transformations, which is `(long, lat)`.
5. Use `geom_sf` to map the points and the shapes.

I think the main advantages of this approach are that you can subsequently use any of the spatial tools you like from `sf`, and the code may be a little more readable. This is probably worth it if you will be making similar plots. Main disadvantages are probably needing the additional packages, including the development version of `ggplot2` to get `geom_sf` (use `devtools::install_github("tidyverse/ggplot2"` to install it). It is also a lot more work than just changing your longitudes to be negative and using your existing code...

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(USAboundaries)

# Define regions
padd1 <- c("CT", "ME", "MA", "NH", "RI", "VT", "NJ", "NY", "PA")
padd2 <- c("IL", "IN", "MI", "OH", "WI", "IA", "KS", "MN", "MO", "NE", "ND",
           "SD")
padd3 <- c("DE", "FL", "GA", "MD", "NC", "SC", "VA", "DC", "WV", "AL", "KY",
           "MS", "TN", "AR", "LA", "OK", "TX")
padd4 <- c("AK", "CA", "HI", "OR", "WA", "AZ", "CO", "ID", "MT", "NV", "NM",
           "UT", "WY")

us_map <- us_states() %>%
  select(state_abbr) # keep only state abbreviation column

cities <- read_csv(here::here("data", "cities.csv")) %>%
  mutate(Long = -Long) %>% # make longitudes negative
  st_as_sf(coords = 3:2) %>% # turn into sf object
  st_set_crs(4326) %>% # add coordinate system
  rename(state_abbr = StateAbbr)

combined <- rbind(us_map, cities) %>%
  filter(!(state_abbr %in% c("AK", "HI", "PR"))) %>% # remove non-contiguous cities and states
  mutate( # add region identifier based on state
    region = case_when(
      state_abbr %in% padd1 ~ "PADD 1: East Coast",
      state_abbr %in% padd2 ~ "PADD 2: Midwest",
      state_abbr %in% padd3 ~ "PADD 3: Gulf Coast",
      state_abbr %in% padd4 ~ "PADD 4: West Coast"
    )
  )

eastc <- combined %>%
  filter(region == "PADD 1: East Coast") %>%
  st_set_geometry(., .$geometry + c(5, 0)) # replace geometries with 5 degrees east
mwest <- combined %>%
  filter(region == "PADD 2: Midwest") %>%
  st_set_geometry(., .$geometry + c(0, 0))
gulfc <- combined %>%
  filter(region == "PADD 3: Gulf Coast") %>%
  st_set_geometry(., .$geometry + c(0, -3))
westc <- combined %>%
  filter(region == "PADD 4: West Coast") %>%
  st_set_geometry(., .$geometry + c(-10, -2))

ggplot(data = rbind(eastc, mwest, gulfc, westc)) + # bind regions together
  theme_bw() +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = region))
```

Here is the output plot
[image: Plot of offset state groups with labels]

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'm unfamiliar with this Tidyverse command for reading in the csv's (``here::here``) Could you be more specific about what goes in "here::here". Thanks

Comment: sorry, just replace everything inside the brackets with the path to the file. `here()` is a function in the `here` package (confusing i know) that makes it easier to specify paths, but you can just replace it with wherever you saved the cities csv